# How do I check for a specific error in Laravel 5.2 validation?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Right now, I can check for a field having a validation error in blade by using:

```
@if($errors->has('field_name'))
 <div class="help-block">
  Lorem Ipsum
 </div>
@endif
```

In my controller, I am using the not_in rule:

`"field_name"  => "required|string|not_in:`

I want to know, can I change the if statement to check only for the not_in rule?

Example:

`@if($errors->has('field_name.not_in'))`

Comment: why you want to check specific rule, if you want to check for specific message based on rule, than you can set message for specific rule

Comment: Yes, and I have. However, I need an anchor tag in the message, and when I placed one in the custom error message, it did not render the html.

Answer (score 1):

```
@if($errors->has('field_name') and $errors->first('field_name') == 'The selected field_name is invalid.')
    this is just for not in validation for special input.
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using Laravel's custom error message.

```
$messages = [
    'field.required' => 'required',
    'field.string' => 'string',
    'field.not_in' => 'not_in',
];
```

Then by doing the following;

```
if($errors->has('field')){
    foreach($errors->get('field') as $error) {
        if($error == "not_in") {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

It is a very messy solution, but I cannot seem to find anything that Laravel provides for a prettier solution. I guess the question is why do you want to do this? There may be a way to provide a more elegant solution rather than working with an error bag.

Comment: I need an anchor tag in the message, and when I placed one in the custom error message, it did not render the html.